# Monty Hall in BBC BASIC and Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, comparative-review, basic-lang

How would I be able to improve the speed of this Monty Hall program?
 Interestingly, the same code written using BBC BASIC for Windows completes the task in half the time of the Python code.

Python:

```
import random

t = 10000001
j = 0
k = 0

for a in range(1, t):
    p = int(random.random() * 3) + 1
    g = int(random.random() * 3) + 1

    if p == g:
        r = int(random.random() * 2) + 1
        if p == 1:
            r += 1
        if p == 2 and r == 2:
            r = 3
    else:
        r = p ^ g
    s = g
    f = g ^ r
    if s == p:
        j = j + 1
    if f == p:
        k = k + 1

print(f"After a total of {t - 1} trials,")
print(f"The 'sticker' won {j} times ({int(j/t*100)}%)")
print(f"The 'swapper' won {k} times ({int(k/t*100)}%)")
```

BBC BASIC for Windows:

```
T% = 10000000

for A% = 1 to T%
  P% = rnd(3)
  G% = rnd(3)
  if P% = G% then

    R% = rnd(2)
    if P% = 1 then R% += 1
    if P% = 2 and R% = 2 then R% = 3
  else
    R% = P% eor G%
  endif
  S% = G%
  F% = G% eor R%
  if S% = P% then J% = J% + 1
  if F% = P% then K% = K% + 1
next

print "After a total of ";T%;" trials,"
print "The 'sticker' won ";J%;" times (";int(J%/T%*100);"%)"
print "The 'swapper' won ";K%;" times (";int(K%/T%*100);"%)"
```

Answer (score 3):

So this is not the typical code review, as the code in question is pretty basic in terms of what it does. It is a given algorithm, and you need to do the given operations. The one possible varying factor is the `random.random()` lines. Can this affects times?

Let us test the random generation of some numbers using various random generators:

```
import random
import numpy
import timeit

t = 100001
def org_random_random(runs=t):
  for a in range(t):
    int(random.random() * 3) + 1

def org_random_randint(runs=t):
  for a in range(t):
    random.randint(1, 3)

def numpy_random_randint(runs=t):
  for a in range(t):
    numpy.random.randint(1, 3)

def numpy_random_randint_x(runs=t):
  numpy.random.randint(1, 3, runs)

orr = timeit.timeit(org_random_random, number=5)
ori = timeit.timeit(org_random_randint, number=5)
nrr = timeit.timeit(numpy_random_randint, number=5)
nrx = timeit.timeit(numpy_random_randint_x, number=5)
```

Sorry for terrible naming, it's just something I threw together, and when I ran it using https://repl.it/languages/Python3, it gave me the following output:

> ```
> org_random_random     : 0.18020408600023075
> org_random_randint    : 0.8966416030016262
> numpy_random_randint  : 0.9019350050002686
> numpy_random_randint_x: 0.004406830999869271
> ```

All three variants has been 'normalised' to produce a number between 1 and 3, and the last variant generates all of the numbers in one go. And the last one is way faster than the other.

In other words, I would suggest to pre-build the random numbers, and make a custom generator feeding you from this pre-built array of random numbers. This would potentially drastically reduce the running time of your algorithm.

### Using a prebuilt random number array

Here is a simple rebuild using a pre-built array of random numbers from numpy:

```
runs = 10000001
random_numbers = numpy.random.randint(1, 3, runs + 6)

j = 0
k = 0

for i in range(1, runs):
    p = random_numbers[i]
    g = random_numbers[i+1]

    if p == g:
        r = random_numbers[i+2] % 2 + 1
        if p == 1:
            r += 1
        if p == 2 and r == 2:
            r = 3
    else:
        r = p ^ g
    s = g
    f = g ^ r
    if s == p:
        j = j + 1
    if f == p:
        k = k + 1

print(f"After a total of {t - 1} trials,")
print(f"The 'sticker' won {j} times ({int(j/t*100)}%)")
print(f"The 'swapper' won {k} times ({int(k/t*100)}%)")
```

When timed (without the `print` statements), this ran about 33% faster than the original. It does kind of reuse the random numbers slightly, but it shouldn't affect the overall randomness too much, I think.

### Other possible factors

Just for the fun of it, I also tried exchanging the `range()` with a `while a < runs` loop, but that only had a minor effect for the larger number of runs. **NB!** If you was using Python 2.x, there would most likely be a massive effect out of changing `range()` into `xrange()`.

The `if s == p` could be eliminated, and the `j += 1` could be moved into the `p == g` block. This also, has little to no effect in my tests.

Lastly, using various python implementation will also effect timings. Using PyPy, IPython, C-Python(?), or other variations could change the time usage. I've used https://repl.it/languages/Python3, which reports the following on `sys.version()`:

> ```
> 3.6.1 (default, Apr 26 2017, 20:23:36) 
> [GCC 4.9.2]
> ```

I also tried with an actual generator with both the large prebuilt list of random numbers, and a loopable generator with 1013 random numbers. Those had similar run times to the original code.

So, with the exception of making a python wrapper and implement the algorithm in another language or re-build the algorithm, I would be surprised to see a faster implementation. But I'll happily be proven wrong!

Comment: Generating random array of length `n` should be 36 times faster then creating random number with `random.random` n times (according to your test), but you only see 33% performance gain. Which makes me think that the bottleneck isn't the random numbers generation.

Comment: Also I think your code is wrong because `1 <= p,q <= 4` and `1 <= r <= 3` (from OP code if I'm correct). but in your code `1 <= p,q,r <= 3`

Comment: You'll loose some of the effect as you need to build a rather large array, and access it somehow. But the random numbers are definitively part of the efficiency equation.

Comment: Well, maybe so, but I still think one should profile first and act later.

Comment: The original BBC Basic rnd ranges are `1..3` for p & q, and `1..2` for `r`. Corrected code.

Comment: @user1685095, In general it is quite correct to profile first, and act later. However, when you have a given algorithm with pure math and some `if` statements you can't optimize away the algorithm unless you provide an alternate implementation in another language (like a python wrapper for a C-equivalent of the algorithm).

Comment: Well... I guess he could use pypy. I haven't profiled the code (I've tried but `plop` gives nonsense, but I would think that the Basic is also more efficient because it has more efficient iteration

Comment: The Basic version uses Resident Integer Variables, represented by variables A% - Z%, now according to documentation on the original BBC BASIC, these variables are 50% faster. After some experimentation using standard variable names i.e monty%, hall%, the code does indeed slow down. So my guess is, this is where the Python bottle neck lays.

Comment: Edster's comment is surprising relevant to the Python side as well. Try the Python code inside a function. Global variables are much slower to access than function locals.

Comment: @MichaelUrman, all my tests are with local variables inside function (with the exception of the number of `runs`)